# Count function in mysql

Tags: php

There are 2 table called employee and approvedcadre.I want to get count of raws where

```
employee.Des_name=approvedcadre.Des_name 
AND employee.service=approvedcadre.service 
AND employee.Grade=approvedcadre.Grade
AND employee.SalaryCode=approvedcadre.SalaryCode 
WHERE app_category='permanent'"
FROM approvedcadre
WHERE Ins_name='$InsName'
```

I herewith attached the current code.but I don't know how to apply "SELECT * FROM  approvedcadre WHERE Ins_name='$InsName' to the query?

[Above mentioned code]

Comment: using left join .. join two tables and use count(*) instead of * in select query. You will get the total rows

Comment: Please, can you format code as code?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it for count the rows

in php use * and use mysqli_num_rows

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM approvedcadre
JOIN employee ON employee.Des_name=approvedcadre.Des_name 
AND employee.service=approvedcadre.service 
AND employee.Grade=approvedcadre.Grade 
AND employee.SalaryCode=approvedcadre.SalaryCode 
WHERE approvedcadre.Ins_name='$InsName' and approvedcadre.app_category='permanent'"
```

Comment: How to add "SELECT * FROM approvedcadre WHERE Insname='$Insname'" to above code?